# Why is this returning a value in Javascript's REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

When I execute this expression in Javascript's REPL (browser's console or node)

`if(false) {4} else {5}`

it returns `5` but I don't understand why.

An `if` isn't returning anything, for exemple I can't do:

`var foo = if(false) {4} else {5}`

So why does REPL return a value?

Answer (score 3):

It is true that `if` statements are statements and do not have a "value". In a normal JS script, nothing would happen when `if(false) {4} else {5}` is evaluated.

What consoles usually give you as a return value is the value of the last evaluated expression.

In your case, `5` is evaluated and returned.

Comment: JavaScript REPL will report 5050 if you try to run `for (var i = 1, s = 0; i <= 100; i++) s += i;`. So it is not the last evaluated expression (which is `i <= 100`, false).

Answer (score 0):

It is called **completion value** of JavaScript statements. The same value `eval()` returns.

- Some statements have completion value. For example, `if (true) { 42; }` have completion value `42`.
- But some statements doesn't have one. For example `var a = 42`.
- If you try to write multiple statements in a row, when last statement doesn't have completion value, it use previous one. For example `'this one'; var a = 42;` will be `'this one'`.
- Completion value does not always be the last evaluated expression. For example, `for(var i = 1, s = 0; i <= 100; i++) s += i;`, last evaluate expression is `i <= 100` (false), and the one before it is `i++` (101). But its completion value is 5050 (result of `s += i`).